# Button for redirecting to url

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

so I have a button here that only clickable, but won't redirect to URL. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
<button class="w-max h-min flex justify-center items-center px-3 py-2 bg-white text-tersiary rounded-xl"href="url here"@click="onclick">{{ btnText }}Button Text!</button>
```

Comment: Are you using vue router?

Comment: yes, turns out just missing <a href="url"> on the button. Wonder why it doesn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using vue router you could do :

```html
<button class="..." @click="$router.push(url here)">{{ btnText }}Button Text!</button>
```